# Newbie question about project structures and makefiles

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a project with this structure

```
/project
    Makefile
    .gitignore
    /bin
    /src
        file1.cpp
        file2.cpp
        file3.cpp
    /include
        definitions.h
    /obj
```

I played around with the Makefile but I couldn't seem to get what I wanted, first I tried:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++2b -Wno-parentheses -Iinclude/

All: build

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

build: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) file1.o file2.o file3.o -o bin/main$(compiler)
```

but this returned the error

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'file1.o', needed by 'build'.  Stop.
```

so I tried

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++2b -Wno-parentheses -Iinclude/

All: build

%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

build: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) file1.o file2.o file3.o -o bin/main$(compiler)
```

and it compiled, putting all the .o files in the main directory, which is unideal. Furthermore, I can't run the binary file unless I specifically opened a terminal in the main directory and enter `./bin/maing++`, opening a terminal in the bin folder and entering `./maing++` doesn't work, and so does running the .exe file manually, what did I do wrong? what I want is all the .o files made in obj/ and to be able to run the executable manually

UPDATE:

I changed the makefile to

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++2b -Wno-parentheses -Iinclude/ -Idoc/

SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst src/%.cpp, obj/%.o, $(SOURCES))

All: build

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

build: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o bin/is$(compiler)
```

this will put all obj files in the correct folder, its a simple program so running the executable would pop up a terminal window and print some text, I'm going to reiterate that I had to specifically open a terminal in the main directory and enter `./bin/maing++`, opening a terminal in the bin folder and entering `./maing++` doesn't work, and so does running the .exe file manually

Comment: You need `obj/file1.o` in your link command. When you try to run the executable what happens?

Comment: Are you sure this is the right makefile? I don't see a dependency of `build` on `%.o`, but the error says it's there.

Comment: the window appears but no code is executed, any key press will kill the window

Comment: What window? Maybe something is wrong with your code?